# Problem of points (Are the 2 formulas equivalent?)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

So, I have this assignment regarding the problem of points:
In a game where each turn is made up of the roll of a die, player E gets 1 point when the die is even, and player O gets 1 point when the die is odd. The first player to accumulate $m$ points wins the pot. Suppose the game is interrupted with E leading $e$ and O with $o$ points. What is the proportion of money that E should get at this juncture? Let probability of die being even be $p$.

So the model answer was that:

Suppose e = 4, o = 2, m = 7.
Each term in the sum corresponds to the probability of winning by exactly a particular score; e.g., starting from 4−2, one can win by 7−2, 7−3, 7−4, 7−5, or 7−6. Each final score requires E to win exactly m−e rounds while the opponent wins exactly i rounds, where i = 0, 1, ..., m − o (the combinatorial term counts the number of ways this can happen).
And thus,
$$ w_e(p,e,o,m) = p^{m-e}\sum_{I=0}^{m-o-1}{i+m-e-1 \choose i }(1-p)^i $$

However, I think that it is equivalent to modelling the problem as: what is the probability of player A winning at least $m-e$ points of the next $(m - e + m - o - 1) $ points (assuming the game has not stopped). Each point is a bernoulli trail with $m - e + m - o - 1 $ trials, and we want to find the probability of at least x successes.

And thus, my formula is:

$$ w_e(p,e,o,m) = \sum_{i=m-e}^{m-o+m-e+1}{m-o+m-e-1 \choose i }p^i(1-p)^{m-o+m-e-i} $$

(and my formula is equivalent to the one as shown in a blog:
https://probabilityandstats.wordpress.com/2016/11/06/the-problem-of-points/)

Hence, I would like to check if the two formulas are equivalent because the output of my formula is the same as the output of the first formula.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Here is my TA's answer:
** The situation is a little bit different with the one you stated. It has the possibility that E and O will need to play (m - e + m - o - 1) additional games to win, but there are also other possibilities that they only need to play (m-e) times. Once E gets (m-e) times of winning, then E just wins the game, and the game will be immediately stopped.  So, we don’t find the probability of at least (m-e) successes, for E, it is just (m-e) successes.

When grading, I also calculate the result of your formula. The results are the same at the current given parameter values, but the core problems they described are different. **

But I do not know how to proof otherwise...

Comment: Tidied up, you question is really whether $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{b}{a+i-1 \choose i}p^a(1-p)^i = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{b}{a+b \choose j}p^{a+b-j}(1-p)^j$ and that is indeed correct due to the combinatorial argument you give

Comment: @Henry Is there any other way to prove that my formula is correct? thank you